# Convert object from localstorage into text

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am outputting objects from a localstorage and I get:

```
"[{\"title\":\"q\",\"ingredients\":\"s\",\"instructions\":\"d\",\"moreingredients\":[],\"moreinstruction\":[],\"img\":{\"jQuery3110052397224993886441\":{\"display\":\"\"}}},{\"title\":\"q\",\"ingredients\":\"w\",\"instructions\":\"e\",\"moreingredients\":[],\"moreinstruction\":[],\"img\":{\"jQuery311079670549304635711\":{\"display\":\"\"}}},{\"title\":\"q\",\"ingredients\":\"w\",\"instructions\":\"e\",\"moreingredients\":[],\"moreinstruction\":[],\"img\":{\"jQuery311016424488798697091\":{\"display\":\"\"}},\"salutation\":\"polish\"},{\"title\":\"q\",\"ingredients\":\"q\",\"instructions\":\"a\",\"moreingredients\":[],\"moreinstruction\":[],\"img\":{\"jQuery311067483883379310751\":{\"display\":\"\"}},\"salutation\":\"italian\"},{\"title\":\"q\",\"ingredients\":\"w\",\"instructions\":\"e\",\"moreingredients\":[],\"moreinstruction\":[],\"img\":{\"jQuery3110317360085863979571\":{\"display\":\"\"}},\"salutation\":\"polish\"}]"
```

However I want to get rid of all the brackets and only have the actual text so instead of

> {\"title\":\"q\"

I want q on the page.

```
var salt;
$("#salutation").change(function() {
  salt = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
});
var existingData = JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem("key")) || [];
document.getElementById("qq").innerHTML +=(existingData);
$('form').submit(function() {
var newArray = [];
    $(".add_id2").each(function(){
    newArray.push($(this).val());
});
var newArray2 = [];
    $(".add_id").each(function(){
    newArray2.push($(this).val());
});
var existingData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("key")) || [];
var newData = {
  'title': $("#title").val(),
  'ingredients': $("#ingredients").val(),
  'instructions': $("#inst").val(),
  'moreingredients': newArray,
  'moreinstruction': newArray2,
  'img': img,
  'salutation': salt,
    };
existingData.push(newData);
localStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(existingData));
```

Answer (score 2):

Values from `localStorage` are always stored as strings. You need to use `JSON.parse()` to convert he string into a valid object, then you can use a for loop to iterate over the json to get the title using `json[i].title`:

```js
var json = "[{\"title\":\"q\",\"ingredients\":\"s\",\"instructions\":\"d\",\"moreingredients\":[],\"moreinstruction\":[],\"img\":{\"jQuery3110052397224993886441\":{\"display\":\"\"}}},{\"title\":\"q\",\"ingredients\":\"w\",\"instructions\":\"e\",\"moreingredients\":[],\"moreinstruction\":[],\"img\":{\"jQuery311079670549304635711\":{\"display\":\"\"}}},{\"title\":\"q\",\"ingredients\":\"w\",\"instructions\":\"e\",\"moreingredients\":[],\"moreinstruction\":[],\"img\":{\"jQuery311016424488798697091\":{\"display\":\"\"}},\"salutation\":\"polish\"},{\"title\":\"q\",\"ingredients\":\"q\",\"instructions\":\"a\",\"moreingredients\":[],\"moreinstruction\":[],\"img\":{\"jQuery311067483883379310751\":{\"display\":\"\"}},\"salutation\":\"italian\"},{\"title\":\"q\",\"ingredients\":\"w\",\"instructions\":\"e\",\"moreingredients\":[],\"moreinstruction\":[],\"img\":{\"jQuery3110317360085863979571\":{\"display\":\"\"}},\"salutation\":\"polish\"}]";
json = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(json);
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(json).length; i++) {
  console.log("Title is: " + json[i].title);
}
```